# Autoresizing UIView with UILabel inside, smoothly

Tags: uiview, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I have a `UIView`, that contains a `UILabel` (and nothing else) inside it. I wish to expand and contract the view, making it look as though the label is expanding and contracting (via a button tap). I'm using a `NSLayoutConstraint` on the height of the view:

```
func labelExpansion() {
    if (isExpanded) {
        myViewConstraint.constant = shortLabelHeight
    } else {
        myViewConstraint.constant = longLabelHeight
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.2, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

The problem is, the text in the label looks like it 'jumps'. As the label is resizing, the position of the text changes, until the animation is finished, when the label correctly redraws to the top of the view.

I have also tried removing the surrounding view, and adjusting the height constraint of the label alone; that was similarly jumpy.

How can I stop this jump during the animation, and fix the top of the label to the top of the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things, I found an easy solution: set the Content Mode of the `UILabel` to 'Top'.

```
myLabel.contentMode = .top
```